# Registering derived repositories as immediately implemented interface

Tags: autofac

I have a situation using Repository Pattern where I would like to have some extra repositories that don't correspond to any entities.

For example here is one that does:

```
 public class TargetRepository : RepositoryBase<Target>, ITargetRepository
{
    public TargetRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        :base(databaseFactory)
    {
    }

            public IEnumerable<Target>  GetValidTargets(){ ... }
}
public interface ITargetRepository : IRepository<Target>
{
            IEnumerable<Target>  GetValidTargets();
}
```

Where `Target` is an entity.

Then I would like to have some other repositories like this:

```
  public class ScatterPlotRepositoryProxy : TargetRepository, IScatterPlotRepositoryProxy
{
    public ScatterPlotRepositoryProxy(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        :base(databaseFactory)
    { }

            public IEnumerable<ScatterPlotModel> GetSavedScatterPlots() {
                   this.GetValidTargets().Select(t => new ScatterPlotModel{ ... });
            }
}

public interface IScatterPlotRepositoryProxy
{
         IEnumerable<ScatterPlotModel> GetSavedScatterPlots()
}
```

Notice how this one inherits from `TargetRepository` not `RepositoryBase<Entity>`. That's because `ScatterPlotModel` is not an entity and is not even persisted. However, I'd like another layer of separation so that my `TargetRespository` doesn't get cluttered up with methods for all different chart types.

I haven't actually implemented this yet, so no errors yet. But I forsee my Autofac DI calls will cause problems later so I'm asking in advance.

How would I correctly register these "repository proxies" with Autofac? Currently I have this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(TargetRepository ).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

And adding this seems like it will conflict:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(TargetRepository ).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("RepositoryProxy")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Will I get the behavior I expect (`IScatterPlotRepositoryProxy` will resolve to `ScatterPlotRepositoryProxy` and `ITargetRepository` should continue to resolve to `TargetRepository` despite `ScatterPlotRepositoryProxy` also implementing it from the base repository)?

Trying to do it all in one shot from the assembly to avoid having to add lines for each repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an abstraction in your system. This is causing you all sorts of trouble and the pain you are already witnessing.

What you need is a common abstraction over queries in the system. This removes the need to have custom repository interfaces. Custom repository interfaces such as `ITargetRepository` violate three out of five [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles and this -without any doubt- leads to all sorts of maintainability issues.

I've written an article about this subject in the past, so I won't repeat myself here (let's keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), but you should definitely read this article: [Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

When applying the architectural guidance given in that article, you will have no problems registering both repositories and queries with Autofac. That will be just a matter of:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>));

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
```

Comment: That was an excellent article and you're a very skilled programmer. It fit extremely well into my existing command architecture. Spot on, thanks!

Comment: Btw had to add `AsImplementedInterface()` to the `IRepository<>` configuration in your answer for it to work. Thanks again

Comment: @Vazgen: I'm not an experienced Autofac user at all, so feel free to update my answer with your corrections. This might help other developers as well.